# C# Remove Span Tags I Insert

Tags: c#, .net, regex, html-parsing

Via a WYSIWYG text editor I insert span tags with a class of "comment".  I want to remove any instances of the span tags and their contents from a string

So how do I get from here:

```
string content = "<p>sadf<span class="otherclass"><span class="comment">asdfsdafsdafsadfsdf</span></span></p>";
```

to here:

```
content = "<p>sadf<span class="otherclass"></span></p>";
```

I know about the HTMLAgilityPack but don't want to add the overhead for HTML that I control.  I perfer a regex solution.

EDIT: I only want to remove spans with the "comment" class.

Comment: why do you think it's overhead to add libraries designed to solve problems that you have?  it's a pretty well accepted fact that regular expression is not a good candidate for parsing HTML, because it can't be guaranteed to be well formed.

Comment: I don't think bad practice should be perpetuated just because the criteria are tailored such that it is forced.

Comment: Because this seems like a cut and dry regex solution.  There will never be any HTML in between the two span tags with the "comment" class, only text.  I'm just not good with Regular Expressions.  Pretend it's not HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inadequate answer:

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"<span\s+class=""comment"">.*?</span>", "");
```

Comment: nice. I missed the other class in there

Comment: In general, the regular expression is not sufficient for such purposes.

Comment: Ended up using "<span class=\".*?comment.*?\">.+?</span>" but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The regex expression to filter your string would be `<span\s+class=\"comment.*?span>`  You might be interested in trying RegexBuddy.  it has helped me figure my regex expressionsvery nicely.

Catch the regex as a string an replace that string against you `string content`

Edit after I realized that you needed to just remove the `<span class="comment"></span>` like BLUEPIXY did.